# How can i use ORDER BY with UNION ALL in a sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, union-all

I have problems with ordering the results of a query that joins 4 different tables with UNION ALL operator.

What I have tried is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT charge, payment, date FROM table_1
UNION ALL
SELECT charge, payment, date FROM table_2
UNION ALL
SELECT charge, payment, date FROM table_3
UNION ALL
SELECT charge, payment, date FROM table_4
) balance
ORDER BY date ASC;
```

when I order by certain parameters it works fine, but there are others that return the data ordered by sections instead of as a whole

When I order by date it works as it should, like this:

```
charge  |  payment  |  date  
------------------------------
   10   |    x      | 2018-03-23
   2    |    x      | 2018-10-20
   8    |    x      | 2019-03-06
   30   |    x      | 2019-05-10
   6    |    x      | 2019-11-10
   15   |    x      | 2020-07-16
   11   |    x      | 2020-09-20
```

but when I order by another parameter, in this case "chage", it orders like this:

```
charge  |  payment  |  date  
------------------------------
   10   |    x      | 2018-03-23
   6    |    x      | 2019-11-10
   30   |    x      | 2019-05-10
   8    |    x      | 2019-03-06
   15   |    x      | 2020-07-16
   11   |    x      | 2020-09-20
   6    |    x      | 2019-11-10
```

Sorry if I don't explain myself well, English is not my first language.

Comment: What you're doing should be correct.  That aside, `date` is a reserved word - if you change the column name, does that fix things?

Comment: Your query [should work as expected](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=49ecd9288d82fe015fed2ffbb55e6e63). Are you sure you're just doing `ORDER BY date ASC`? Just the `date` column?

Comment: I noticed that when I order by date, in fact, I have no problem, but when I order by the other parameters. I used date because I thought it was the clearest to explain :/

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags. Please include a specific database tag only,

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you don't even need the subquery, the following should work:

```sql
SELECT charge, payment, date FROM table_1
UNION ALL
SELECT charge, payment, date FROM table_2
UNION ALL
SELECT charge, payment, date FROM table_3
UNION ALL
SELECT charge, payment, date FROM table_4
ORDER BY date;
```

The final `ORDER BY` clause applies to the entire union query.

Comment: yes, you are right, anyway i still have the problem. I really don't know what it could be, because when sorting by date it works well but with other data it doesn't.

Comment: If my answer doesn't give you the output you expect, then what output do you want to see here?

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and put minimal sample data there, as _text_, not as images.

Comment: @estebanovic I don't see any "ordering by sections". What I do see is that "abono" is a string so it is ordered as a string not a number

Comment: @MartinSmith ok i changed it

Comment: You changed the text in your question to something not shown in your actual screenshot you posted above

Comment: @MartinSmith you're right. the fields are integers, but following the old code where in the tables that there were no values I changed it to an empty string, that made them compare as strings. thanks and sorry if i bothered you with my mistake.

Comment: @estebanovic If that's the issue here, that you can try ordering using `CAST(some_field AS int)`, where `some_field` is a text column however containing numbers.  Best practice is that if you need to use casts all over the place, the `some_field` column should probably be numeric, rather than text.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, change the empty string to a zero in the default cases and now it works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

When you apply ORDER BY at the end of UNION ALL, it is applied to whole resultset.

The logical order of processing a sql query is given below. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement). So, the `ORDER BY`  is applied after `UNION ALL` application.

1. FROM
2. ON
3. JOIN
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY
11. TOP

```sql
DECLARE @table1 table (charge  char(1),  payment char(1),  dateval date)
DECLARE @table2 table (charge  char(1),  payment char(1),  dateval date)
DECLARE @table3 table (charge  char(1),  payment char(1),  dateval date)
DECLARE @table4 table (charge  char(1),  payment char(1),  dateval date)

insert into @table1 values('x','x','2018-03-23')
insert into @table2 values('x','x','2019-03-06')
insert into @table3 values('x','x','2019-11-10')
insert into @table4 values('x','x','2020-09-20')

Select * from @table1
UNION ALL
Select * from @table2
union all
Select * from @table3
union all
Select * from @table4
order by dateval
```

| charge | payment | dateval |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | x | 2018-03-23 |
| x | x | 2019-03-06 |
| x | x | 2019-11-10 |
| x | x | 2020-09-20 |